# How to iterate over an Object's specific keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration

I have an object and I want to iterate over some specific keys of that object. How to achieve this?

Consider the snippet below:

How can I iterate over table1,table2 and table3 keys and not all of them?

```js
var table_object = {
  table1: "hello world",
  table1_name: "greetings_english.html",
  table2: "hola",
  table2_name: "greetings_spanish.html",
  table3: "Bonjour",
  table3_name: "greetings_french.html"
};
```

Comment: Instead of `for (var key in table_object)` just use `for (var key of ["table1",
 …])`?

Comment: It can be, but the keys will be dynamically created on an event's occurrence and named considering the number of files.

Comment: Then maybe you want to store the number of files, and use `for (var i=1; i<=fileCount; i++) { var key = "table"+i; … }`

Comment: Or maybe it would be much easier if you stored the `tables` and `tablenames` as two separate arrays.

Comment: Why did you tag this jquery if you want vanilla js?

Comment: I think it is not the right way to make a table. Making two or more arrays, you can note a table, and iterate through the rows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could filter the keys and then iterate the rest.

```js
var table_object = { table1: "hello world", table1_name: "greetings_english.html", table2: "hola", table2_name: "greetings_spanish.html", table3: "Bonjour", table3_name: "greetings_french.html" };

Object
    .keys(table_object)
    .filter(function (k) { return !/_/.test(k); })
    .forEach(function (k) { console.log(table_object[k]); });
```

Comment: `/^table(\d+)$/` will explicitly match `table` followed by some digits.

Comment: @NinaScholz not a prefix, it's wrapped in `^$`.

Comment: `/^([a-zA-Z0-9$]+)$/`, or `/^([a-zA-Z$]+)(\d+)$/`. Or you can **change** the regex, or the whole filter function.

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify which keys you have to iterate through:

```js
var table_object = {
  table1: "hello world",
  table1_name: "greetings_english.html",
  table2: "hola",
  table2_name: "greetings_spanish.html",
  table3: "Bonjour",
  table3_name: "greetings_french.html"
};

var keysToIterateThrough = ["table1", "table2", "table3"];
keysToIterateThrough.forEach(key => {
    var value = table_object[key];
    console.log(`key: ${key} => value: ${value}`);
})
```

Comment: Is an option, but filtering by regex is also an option.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `Object.keys` in order to find out all the object keys then apply a `filter` method in order to **filter** them.

```js
var table_object = {
  table1: "hello world",
  table1_name: "greetings_english.html",
  table2: "hola",
  table2_name: "greetings_spanish.html",
  table3: "Bonjour",
  table3_name: "greetings_french.html"
};
var keysToIterate = ["table1", "table2", "table3_name"];
let values=Object.keys(table_object)
                .filter(a=>keysToIterate.includes(a))
                .map(a=> table_object[a]);
console.log(values);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler (and probably more efficient) to do `keysToIterate.filter(a => a in table_object)` instead of `Object.keys(table_object).filter(a => keysToIterate.includes(a))`?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, no, because `keysToIterate` is the array with keys we needed. He have to filter the keys of object.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, that would work. Whether it's more efficient depends on how large the object usually is and how often the `keysToIterate` are not part of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Could try something like

```
var keys = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3']
Object.keys(table_object).forEach(function(key) {
    if (keys.indexOf(key) != -1) {
        var table_value = table_object[key]
    }
})
```

Comment: You can speed it up by iterating over `keys`.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be possible to iterate over limited keys, but you can have an array of keys which you want to iterate. Then loop over that array to get the corresponding value from the object

```js
var objKeys = ['table1', 'table2', 'table3']

var table_object = {
  table1: "hello world",
  table1_name: "greetings_english.html",
  table2: "hola",
  table2_name: "greetings_spanish.html",
  table3: "Bonjour",
  table3_name: "greetings_french.html"
};

objKeys.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(table_object[item])

})
```

Comment: `for ( var i = 0; i < objKeys.length; i ++ ) {}` is supported in almost every browser and every version of that.

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to do it in this case is making your object like this:

```js
var table = {
    "hello world": "greetings_english.html",
    "hola": "greetings_spanish.html",
    "bonjour": "greetings_french.html"
};

for( var i in table ) {
    console.log( i );
    console.log( table[ i ] );
}
```

Or you could create two arrays:

```js
var greetings = [
    "hello world",
    "hola",
    "bonjour"
];
var names = [
    "greetings_english.html",
    "greetings_spanish.html",
    "greetings_french.html"
];

for( var i = 0; i < greetings.length; i ++ ) {
    console.log( greetings[ i ] );
    console.log( names[ i ] );
}
```

You can make a table using this method

But in any case of your question:

```js
var table = {
    table1: "hello world",
    table1_name: "greetings_english.html",
    table2: "hola",
    table2_name: "greetings_spanish.html",
    table3: "bonjour",
    table3_name: "greetings_french.html"
};

// Now there are three methods

console.log( "--- Method 1 ---" );
Object.keys( table )
      .filter( function( key ) {
          return /^table(\d+)$/.test( key );
      } )
      .forEach( function( key ) {
          console.log( key );
          console.log( table[ key ] );
          console.log( table[ key + "_name" ] );
      } );
      
console.log( "--- Method 2 ---" );
for ( var i in table ) {
    if ( /^table(\d+)$/.test( i ) ) {
        console.log( i );
        console.log( table[ i ] );
        console.log( table[ i + "_name" ] );
    }
}
      
console.log( "--- Method 3 ---" );
var keys = [
    "table1",
    "table2",
    "table3"
];
for ( var i = 0; i < keys.length; i ++ ) {
    console.log( keys[ i ] );
    console.log( table[ keys[ i ] ] );
    console.log( table[ keys[ i ] + "_name" ] );
}
```

Method 2 would be the best.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need fancy filters or regular expression to accomplish such a simple task! Ignore those misleading answers and start using the full power of JavaScript! 
 You should use the `Object.defineProperty()` method on your object and set to `enumerable: false` all the properties you don't want to iterate through. In this way you also decouple your naming convention from your logic. Let me show you:

```js
// Defining iterable properties. This ones will be returned
// by Object.keys()

var table_object = {
  table1: "hello world",
  table2: "hola",
  table3: "Bonjour",
  // It works even if you declare them in advance
  // table1_name: "greetings_english.html",
  // table2_name: "greetings_spanish.html",
  // table3_name: "greetings_french.html",
};

// Declaring the not iterable properties. They can still be
// accessed, but they will not be iterated through

Object.defineProperty(table_object, "table1_name", {
  // delete the next line if you have already declared it
  value: "greetings_english.html", 
  enumerable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(table_object, "table2_name", {
  // delete the next line if you have already declared it
  value: "greetings_spanish.html",
  enumerable: false
});

Object.defineProperty(table_object, "table3_name", {
  // delete the next line if you have already declared it
  value: "greetings_french.html",
  enumerable: false
});

// Iterating through the object using for ... in, which iterates
// over the keys

for (var key in table_object) {
  console.log(table_object[key]);
}
```

The not enumerable properties can still be retrieved along with all the enumerable ones using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`. 

However, if you are planning to actually use this second method to iterate through all the properties when filtering is not needed anymore I've to give you some advice:

- `enumerable` can be set back to `true`, so if it a one-time change I'd highly suggest to revert it.
- If filtering is toogled back and forth more often than not, then you should check twice the structure of your object, since there may be more suitable options for your needs (such as arrays into the object).

Comment: I thought about that but it's much slower than filtering the keys.

Comment: Also, if you really care about performance, why not using [loops over filter function?](https://jsperf.com/array-filter-performance). I'm not saying this is the fastest solution, of course, but I think that's the most semantically correct one and, most important thing, it's not that slow to freeze your browser ;P